# Moving files between libraries change version history

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, version-history

Moving files from one library to another (within the same site) in SharePoint 2016 on prem seems to affect version history? All names in the column *Modified by* are changed to the person who moved the document. Also, all changes in metadata will be moved/visible in the latest version of the particular document in the version history.

I can reproduce this in a clean SharePoint 2016 environment. This happens when using file explorer or when moving files with drag'n drop directly in the browser.

Is this a known bug?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior since version histories do not carry with the document when you move it on most occasions.

In addition to the first Answer: If you have **publishing features** activated on this site, you can use **[Content and Structure](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/work-with-site-content-and-structure-30fcaad9-02b1-4347-8b03-e1ccc5a4c19f#bm4)** under Site Settings to move the document, which will retain all version history safely.

You can also refer to the link here for a sample PowerShell script to move files with version history: [Move Files Between Document Libraries with Metadata and Version History.](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/06/move-files-between-document-libraries-with-metdata-version-history.html)

Comment: Content and structure worked, thanks. Still, recommending this "tool" to ordinary users seems a bit off... why is Microsoft even implementing drag'n drop-functionality if it's not working properly? Moving files in any way should never affect versioning.

Answer (score 1):

When you move a file, version history starts at 0 again. SharePoint introduces it's own versions when creating the file (so there are versions prior to you initially working on it). When you move files this way, the Created/Modified values are updated to the individual who performed the Move action.

If you do not want to modify metadata in any way, a migration tool like Sharegate is the route to go. It can be accomplished with PowerShell, as well, but that is complex and may require custom PoSh to preserve specific columns.